# Unable to run Spring Boot WebMVC with Thymeleaf support

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have search a lot but I did not find answer to my question, So I am posting my question here. Please look and suggest me the solution where I am mistaken.

I have created spring boot web mvc project with thymeleaf support using Spring Tool Suite(STS). When I run it give me "Whitelabel Error Page" page. Which means mapping not found.

**Efforts:**

WebConfig.java

```
package com.springthymeleaf.config;

import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.springthymeleaf")
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {

    @Bean
    ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistration(){
        ServletRegistrationBean registrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean();
        registrationBean.addUrlMappings("/console/*");
        return registrationBean;
    }

    //start Thymeleaf specific configuration
    @Bean(name ="templateResolver") 
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver getTemplateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
//      templateResolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("XHTML");
    return templateResolver;
    }
    @Bean(name ="templateEngine")       
    public SpringTemplateEngine getTemplateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(getTemplateResolver());
    return templateEngine;
    }
    @Bean(name="viewResolver")
    public ThymeleafViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver(); 
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(getTemplateEngine());
    return viewResolver;
    }
    //end Thymeleaf specific configuration
    @Bean(name ="messageSource")
    public MessageSource getMessageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("/WEB-INF/i18/thymeleafResource");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

SecurityConfiguration.java

```
package com.springthymeleaf.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
    }
}
```

ServletInitializer.java

```
package com.springthymeleaf;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringThymeLeafApplication.class);
    }

}
```

SpringThymeLeafApplication.java

```
package com.springthymeleaf;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringThymeLeafApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringThymeLeafApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

IndexController.java

```
package com.springthymeleaf.controllers;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

I have created `index.html` file in resources/templates folder. Still I am getting that error. I have searched a lot on web, but did not get clue. Please somebody help me.

[image: Directory Structure]

Comment: Remove your web configuration class. Spring Boot configures that for you already. For the I18N support add `spring.messages.basename=/WEB-INF/i18/thymeleafResource` to your `application.properties`. In short work with the framework not around the framework.

Comment: I have removed the WebConfig.java file and for now i don't want to use any resource too, so i have not configured resource bundle. After this i have tried to to run i am still getting the same issue.

Comment: Add your directory structure. Also the error page could mean something completely different, check your logs for an error (and add that stack trace / error to your question).

Comment: I have updated my question with directory structure screenshot. Please look and suggest me solution.

Comment: i have also added error.html page in templates folder. Now whenever i tried to access any page it show me only error.html page not the actual page form indexcontroller which is index.html in templates folder for "/" mapping.

Comment: As requested post the actual stack trace... There might be something else wrong with your config. I assume you have `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` in your pom.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111842/discussion-between-mandy-and-m-deinum).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually Spring Boot configures Thymeleaf out of the box. It should work with the following setup:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/").permitAll() // http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-form
                .and()
            .logout().permitAll(); // http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-logout
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception
    {
        web
            .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**"/*, ... */);
    }
}

@Controller
public class LoginController
{
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    static String login(Model model)
    {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Comment: Not its not working. It taking me to the login page without context root path.

Comment: @Mandy
I did a mistake in LoginController Annotation. Change "/" to "/login"... And what do you mean with "without context root path"? The setting above should protect any request and should redirect to login page under "/login". After successfull Login it should redirect to "/".

Comment: Here we need something more which will let me do the actual project to working. I would also thanks M. Deinum without his guidance i will not achieve my task. Thanks Deinum.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot already configures Thymeleaf for you, so no need to configure that manually. Remove all Thymeleaf related configuration, also remove `@EnableWebMvc` as that interferes with the Spring Boot auto configuration. The `@ComponentScan` is also redundant.

Spring Boot also registered a `MessageSource` for you so no need to configure that. Not sure what the servlet registration is you do but that is the only thing you need.

Also I suggest to remove your controller and use a view controller which you can configure in your `WebConfig` class. Saves you a controller.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {

    @Bean
    ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistration(){
        ServletRegistrationBean registrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean();
        registrationBean.addUrlMappings("/console/*");
        return registrationBean;
    }

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
    }
}
```

To let the auto configured message source pickup your custom bundles add the following to `src/main/resources/application.properties`.

```
spring.messages.basename=/WEB-INF/i18/thymeleafResource
```

I would also suggest to simply let the `SpringThymeLeafApplication` extend the `SpringBootServletInitializer`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringThymeLeafApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringThymeLeafApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringThymeLeafApplication.class);
    }
}
```

Also make sure that your templates are in `src/main/resources/templates` and not in `src/main/resources/resources/templates` else those will not be found.

Comment: I have done all the thing you have mention. I have remove everything like webconfig.java and anything which is related to thymeleaf. there is only security configuration and boot configuration. I have also created error.html page in template. not error page showing instead controller page.

Comment: Thank Deinum without your help i will not do further. as your answer and shinchillahh's answer allow me to go further. Here i can accept only one answer, but upvote for you.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot does all the automatic configuration when you add the thymeleaf dependency. then you should do the following.

1. Remove all the thymeleaf configuration you have on your WebConfig.java
2. Make sure you have the following dependency your pom.xml if you are using Maven, otherwise check the spring website for the equivalent if you are using gradle:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. thirdly you make sure that you scanning where your controllers are, add the following on your SpringThymeLeafApplication.java:

   @ComponentScan(basePackages = "your.path.to.controllers")
4. Finally you have to add your .html files to resources/templates