# Unable to add css file in spring and thymeleaf

Tags: css, spring, thymeleaf

I am unable to add my css file using thymeleaf in my spring project.My css file is in static/css folder.

I have tried two ways:

```
<link  href="../../static/css/auth.css" th:href="@{auth.css}" type="text/css">


 <link  href="../../static/css/auth.css" th:href="auth.css" type="text/css">
```

My Head tag:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Login</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link  href="../../static/css/auth.css" th:href="auth.css" type="text/css">


</head>
```

Comment: use `/css/auth.css` etc

Comment: not working tried everything

Comment: The proper syntax for Thymeleaf would be `th:href="@{/css/auth.css}"`.   See the Thymeleaf docs for examples.  Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29562471/springboot-with-thymeleaf-css-not-found

Comment: Thanku @bphilipnyc